# WKWebView goes to about:blank page after appearing

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView and it has a randomly occuring bug when I leave the WebView ViewController to another "native" ViewController and come back, it shows nothing but a white screen. I debugged with Safari and find that the WKWebView shows a page "about:blank" with an empty head and body tag as content.

The phenomena occurs completely at random. Sometimes I leave the WKWebView 3 times, sometimes I do it over 100 times until the white screen appears.

It doesn´t fire any of the WKNavigationDelegate's Callbacks for the "about:blank" page. My logs are the same then if the WebView works normal. We have no idea what`s going on. Anyone experienced similar behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I have never experienced similar behavior however, I can think of a solution. How about you save in a variable the last page visited and reload it on viewWillAppear if _wkWebView.URL is the blank page?

Also maybe the delegate is being deallocated, make sure you reassign the delegate on viewWillAppear

Comment: I can´t. in viewWillAppear I obtain the current HTML content, but at that point it`s always nil. I read getting the HTML content only works after the page finished loading, but that doesn´t happen at all for me (no callbacks).

Comment: If the ViewController is remaining in the backstack of the navigation controller and never destroyed the public properties of the ViewController will never be deallocated from memory. Thus you can save the last html page visited, and reload it. However, if it is being destroyed and deallocated that is another issue. You will need to save the last visited page somewhere, maybe NSUserDefaults? And then check your WkWebView if it is a blank page reload the page with that saved URL

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. I will try that. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I know it's quite old but were you able to fix it? What was the root cause of this? How can you debug to find the root cause